# Adding Intent putextra method taking time

Tags: android

I am adding some large serializable object (say data) to the Intent's putextra() method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentScreen, newScreen.getClass());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
intent.putExtra("DATA", data);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
currentScreen.startActivity(intent);
```

newScreen taking much time to start and display.

Please let me know how to overcome the issue.

Thanks
Android_IT

Comment: did u try it on the phone or just the emulator?

Comment: How large is your data? And what is your data? Serializable is very slow, you should look at Parcelable, or pass it as a byte array or something else. Obviously this depends on what your data is.

Comment: I debug the code and found that de serialization taking time to delay the next activity. Any way to reduce this time.

Comment: Like I said, [serialization on Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13138) is slow. You might be able to use Parcelable but you haven't said what 'data' is. Otherwise, you can use an DataOutputStream of some sort and manage the process yourself. There are many ways to 'serialize' or persist data; the most appropriate depends on *what* the data is.

Comment: data is complex object containing several complex serialzable objects for parsing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just assume the large extra data is causing your app to be slow. Profile it with [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and make sure. If it does indeed turn out to be the problem, my only suggestion is to store it in a static member before starting the new activity and then retrieve it from there. This way it will not be copied around and serialized/deserialized.

Comment: I cant use static members, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If NewScreen take too much time you are probably doing some time consuming task in the onCreate method of NewScreen.See what is happening there by printing some log to see whether onCreate of newScreen fired immediately or not